# Adding Ui labels values

Tags: swift, user-interface, slider, label

I have been attempting to Add the values of some UI labels in Xcode, but with '+' there is an error and I have not found any other way yet to have it work.
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvltm.png)

[ViewController.Swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEnt2.png)

Comment: what do you wanna do?

Comment: Send the Error.. Alan Stricklin

Comment: I added Pictures of my code, I backtracked a little bit trying to find new ways to approach my issue and do not have that particular error.

Answer (score 0):

It‘s not clear in your question but I think you’re trying to change the text displayed by the UILabel. If this is the case, you can do this as following

```
myLabel.text = “myText”
```

or

```
myLabel.text += “Test”
```

Comment: Sorry I did not give enough information the first time I posted this question, good answer, though not one that i benefit from currently.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific. I don’t really get what you want to add so I will assume.

If you want to add the Strings the UILabels contain, you should do as Bruce said above.

If you want to add the two strings into a variable you should do this.

```
Var outcome = label1.text + label2.text
```

The outcome would be the string of label one plus the string of label two connected.

Now if the labels contain numbers and you want to add those numbers you should do this. (Assuming they do contain Integers)

```
let num1 = label1.text.toInt()
let num2 = label2.text.toInt()
let outcome = num1 + num2
```

In your case it would be....:

```
Let sumOfIntegers = MathCriAValue.text.toInt() + MathCriBValue.text.toInt() + MathCriCValue.text.toInt() + MathCriDValue.text.toInt()
```

Comment: When I tried this answer I got the error "of type 'String?' has no member 'toInt'". Do I need to modify something within my labels for Xcode to recognize that the values are integers?